# How do I merge cells in EPPlus library, but in columns?

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I can't seem to find any solution. I know of the MergeCells() property, but that only seems to work in rows. I need to merge cells from A2:A10 for instance. Or is there a way to use the existing function for vertical merging as well?

Comment: You can't just work with Excel in ASP.NET. You need to either use Excel Interop, or a library like EPPlus. In both cases merging is possible. Without looking at the docs I'd guess that `MergeCells()` or the equivalent property, is a member on a `Range` of cells, not on the `Sheet`. In the Excel programming model almost everything works on ranges, not the sheet itself. This means you need to select the range you want first and then call `Merge`. In EPPlus you'd write `ws.Cells["A1:A10"].Merge = true;`

Comment: Which library are you using? What does your code look like? You'll probably find a duplicate question if you search for your specific library, eg `EPPlus merge rows` or `NPOI merge rows` or `ClosedXML merge rows`

Comment: Forgot to mention I was working in EPPlus, my bad

Comment: Have you tried `ws.Cells["A2:A10"].Merge = true` ?

Comment: I have learned that the correct syntax is `worksheet.Cells[FromRow, FromColumn, ToRow, ToColumn].Merge = true;` Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that the correct syntax is worksheet.Cells[FromRow, FromColumn, ToRow, ToColumn].Merge = true; Thanks everyone